# Do I need a permit to open a wall up for a kitchen passthrough?

Tags: load-bearing, permitting

I'm interested in opening the wall between the kitchen and the "Dining Room" in an apartment that I'm renting. Before I pitch this to the landlord, do I need a permit for making that kind of modification in a non load-bearing wall? realistically I would only be cutting through one 2x4 and building a header in for the span.

Comment: Seems like a location is critically relevant here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because permitting questions are off-topic

Comment: Question is general enough to be useful, no need to close.

Comment: I would get a permit **because it's rented**.  Because if the job is done illegally, you're not on the hook, the landlord is.  Attention to details like this is a powerful sway.   Once I made huge points with a landlord when I accidentally broke a $40 custom fixture glass, called him up, "hey, where do you buy those fixtures?" and fixed it on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in the US, you generally don't need a permit for cosmetic changes. Everything else you do. To find out for sure contact your local government building department.

Comment: I would say *nearly* everything else, and what needs to be considered here is any electrical and plumbing in the wall that would need to be moved. As a counter-point, I don't know of any jurisdictions that require permits for low voltage wiring (telephone, cable, network), and I think you're generally okay with minor changes to HVAC as well (eg, moving a vent).